# How to import elasticsearch-hadoop dependency to spark script

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, cassandra

Im trying to use [spark-es connector](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) by setting the Build.scala document to:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.2.1",
    "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.2.0"
  )
```

but I getting the error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-hadoop_2.10;2.2.0: not found
```

And I can see that it is exists [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/2.2.0/)...

**EDIT:**

When I change my Build.scala to:

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.2.0"
```

I got the following error:

```
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elasticsearch-hadoop` is not a Scala dependency so it doesn't have Scala specific version and cannot be used with `%%`. Try

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.2.0"
```